# can't get the exception of wcf under iis

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, exception

We are running a WCF service on IIS which is throwing an an exception.

However, even with `includeException = true` in the `serviceBehavior` configuration section and `compile = debug` no exception details are revealed and only a generic message recommending that you enable the attribute mentioned.

How do I get WCF to show the real error?

Comment: Hve you restarted IIS since the includeException and serveiceBehavior attributes were changed?

Comment: yes i have stoped and started the app pool. and the web config was set with this attribute in the beginning. its a new server for testing, on other servers we dont have that problem

Comment: Check your event log. If this doesn't reveal anything then enable diagnostic tracing on your service. IIS won't propagate service faults for you. It will only tell you if there is an issue with your [hosting] configuration.

Comment: OK the windows event logger did not have any info, i will activate the tracing.

Comment: Do you have the code for the server? If you do, can you attach the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have following two entries set as true under serviceBehaviors section

```
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.